# layout structure- html and css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a concept which I am struggling to create see image . I have started this and this is what I have done so far. https://jsfiddle.net/o0zmtr3q/2/ How will I make every box unique. I am particularly struggling with the first layout having the text in different places and having the svg beside the 100,000 and readers at the bottom.

[image]

```css
/*Legal Notice Styling*/ .featured--legal--notices { position: relative; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; background:#1A1A1A; } .featured--legal--notices .btn-legal { position: absolute; top: 89%; left: 28%; transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #01AD54; color: #fff; font-size: 16px; padding: 12px 24px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; } .legal-overlay-logo{margin-top: 1rem; margin-left:
43%;} .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay { position: absolute; top: 55%; left: 55%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 15rem; } .featured--legal--notices
.legal-overlay h2 { font-size: 28px; color: #fff; text-transform:uppercase; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay p { font-size: 18px; color: #fff; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay i { font-size: 16px; color: #fff; } .featured--legal--notices
.legal-overlay-white { position: absolute; top: 71%; left: 45%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white p { font-size: 16px; color: #fff; } @media only screen
and (max-width: 1200px) { .featured--legal--notices .bob-logo { position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 34%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--legal--notices .btn-listen { position: absolute;
top: 80%; left: 55%; transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #fff; color: #01ad54; font-size: 12px; padding: 8px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; text-transform:
uppercase; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay { position: absolute; top: 55%; left: 60%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay { position: absolute;
top: 56%; left: 32%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white { position: absolute; top: 65%; left: 35%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white p { font-size: 14px; color: #fff; } } @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) { .featured--legal--notices .bob-logo { position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 34%; transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--legal--notices .btn-listen { position: absolute; top: 80%; left: 55%; transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #fff;
color: #01ad54; font-size: 12px; padding: 8px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay { position: absolute; top: 56%; left: 29%; transform: translate(-50%,
-50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white p { font-size: 14px; color: #fff; } } /*END OF legal notice STYLING*/ /*Readers Styling*/ .featured--readers { position: relative; height: 300px;
overflow: hidden; background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 118, 57) 0%, rgb(39, 173, 84) 100%); ; } .featured--readers .btn-readers { position: absolute; top: 89%; left: 28%; transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color:
#1A1A1A; color: #fff; font-size: 16px; padding: 12px 24px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; } .readers-overlay-logo{margin-top: 2rem; margin-left: 43%;} .featured--readers .readers-overlay
{ position: absolute; top: 55%; left: 55%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 17rem; } .featured--readers .readers-overlay h1 { color: #fff; text-transform:uppercase;
margin: 0; } .featured--readers .readers-overlay p { font-size: 18px; color: #fff; } .featured--readers.readers-overlay i { font-size: 16px; color: #fff; } .featured--readers.readers-overlay-white { position: absolute; top: 71%; left: 55%; transform:
translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--readers .readers-overlay-white p { font-size: 16px; color: #fff; } @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) { .featured--readers .bob-logo { position: absolute;
top: 20%; left: 34%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--readers .btn-readers { position: absolute; top: 80%; left: 55%; transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: #1A1A1A; color: #fff; font-size: 12px; padding: 8px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; } .featured--readers .readers-overlay { position: absolute; top: 55%; left: 60%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--readers .readers-overlay { position: absolute; top: 56%; left: 32%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer;
} .featured--readers .readers-overlay-white { position: absolute; top: 65%; left: 35%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--readers .readers-overlay-white p { font-size: 14px; color: #fff;
} } @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) { .featured--readers .bob-logo { position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 34%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--readers .btn-readers { position:
absolute; top: 80%; left: 55%; transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #1A1A1A;; color: #fff; font-size: 12px; padding: 8px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; text-transform:
uppercase; } .featured--readers .readers-overlay { position: absolute; top: 56%; left: 29%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--readers.readers-overlay-white p { font-size: 14px; color:
#fff; } } /*END OF Readers STYLING*/ /*subscribe Styling*/ .featured--subscribe { position: relative; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 118, 57) 0%, rgb(39, 173, 84) 100%); color: #fff; ; } .featured--subscribe
.btn-subscribe { position: absolute; top: 89%; left: 20%; transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #1A1A1A; color: #fff; font-size: 16px; padding: 12px 24px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius:
5px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; } .subscribe-overlay-logo{margin-top: 2rem; margin-left: 43%;} .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay { position: absolute; top: 45%; left: 60%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%,
-50%); cursor: pointer; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 17rem; } .featured--subscribe .readers-subscribe p { font-size: 18px; color: #fff; } .featured--subscribe.subscribe-overlay i { font-size: 16px; color: #fff; } .featured--subscribe.subscribe-overlay-white
{ position: absolute; top: 71%; left: 45%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay-white p { font-size: 16px; color: #fff; } @media only screen and (max-width:
1200px) { .featured--subscribe .bob-logo { position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 34%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--subscribe .btn-subscribe { position: absolute; top: 80%; left: 55%;
transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #1A1A1A; color: #fff; font-size: 12px; padding: 8px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; } .featured--subscribe
.subscribe-overlay { position: absolute; top: 55%; left: 60%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay { position: absolute; top: 56%; left: 32%; transform: translate(-50%,
-50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay-white { position: absolute; top: 65%; left: 35%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor: pointer; } .featured--subscribe
.subscribe-overlay-white p { font-size: 14px; color: #fff; } } @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) { .featured--subscribe .bob-logo { position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 34%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
cursor: pointer; } .featured--subscribe .btn-subscribe { position: absolute; top: 80%; left: 55%; transform: translate(5%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #1A1A1A;; color: #fff; font-size: 12px; padding: 8px 20px; border:
none; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; } .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay { position: absolute; top: 56%; left: 29%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); cursor:
pointer; } .featured--subscribe.subscribe-overlay-white p { font-size: 14px; color: #fff; } } /*END OF Readers STYLING*/
```

```html
<div class="col-4 featured-news-wrapper">
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="featured--readers">

      <div class="readers-overlay-logo">

      </div>
      <div class="readers-overlay">
        <!-- svg beside main text -->
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="58.373" height="63.352" viewBox="0 0 58.373 63.352">
              <path id="Path_1275" data-name="Path 1275" d="M34.794,67.261l.22-26.139a.173.173,0,0,0-.312-.1L26.813,51.883A8.568,8.568,0,0,1,13.291,41.36a8.57,8.57,0,0,1,6.589-15.82l11.983,5.469a.167.167,0,0,0,.224-.086.152.152,0,0,0-.027-.177L22.875,19.514A8.57,8.57,0,0,1,36.5,9.115a8.568,8.568,0,0,1,13.619,10.4L41.211,30.4a.175.175,0,0,0,.022.241.179.179,0,0,0,.176.027l12.637-5.066a8.57,8.57,0,0,1,5.839,16.114,8.567,8.567,0,0,1-14,9.874L39.119,41.285a.169.169,0,0,0-.237-.049.181.181,0,0,0-.081.146,40.994,40.994,0,0,0,3.65,16.554Zm6.346-9.5a42.025,42.025,0,0,1-3.46-16.372,1.3,1.3,0,0,1,2.377-.719L46.8,50.955a7.447,7.447,0,0,0,12.037-8.773,7.124,7.124,0,0,0-.988-1.1,7.447,7.447,0,1,0-3.408-14.419L41.821,31.717a1.3,1.3,0,0,1-1.481-2.023l8.89-10.876A7.444,7.444,0,1,0,37.255,9.974a7.271,7.271,0,0,0-.758,1.272,7.445,7.445,0,1,0-13.489,6.3,7.005,7.005,0,0,0,.751,1.266l9.17,11.22a1.289,1.289,0,0,1-1.534,1.99L19.434,26.575a7.445,7.445,0,1,0-5.506,13.834,7.219,7.219,0,0,0,1.421.407,7.445,7.445,0,0,0,9.53,11.44,7.1,7.1,0,0,0,1.041-1.051L33.792,40.36a1.295,1.295,0,0,1,2.34.768l-.188,22.967Z" transform="translate(-7.591 -5.321)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
            </svg>
        <!-- main text -->
        <h1>100,000 </h1>
        <!-- sub text-->
        <p> Readers<br>with advertising </p>
      </div>
      <!-- text at the top -->
      <div class="readers-overlay-white">
        <p>Reach Over</p>

      </div>
      <!-- readers button -->
      <button class="btn-readers">Learn More</button>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4 featured-news-wrapper">
  <a href="   ">
    <div class="featured--legal--notices">

      <div class="legal-overlay-logo">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="62.576" height="62.344" viewBox="0 0 62.576 62.344">
              <path id="gavel-solid" d="M59.516,23.5l-2.667-2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0-4,0l-.667.667L38.847,8.162l.667-.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0-4L36.847.828a2.829,2.829,0,0,0-4,0L18.179,15.5a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0,4l2.667,2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,4,0l.667-.667,4.667,4.667-9.551,9.551-.667-.667a3.771,3.771,0,0,0-5.334,0L1.1,48.571a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,0,5.334l5.334,5.334a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,5.334,0L25.3,45.715a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,0-5.334l-.667-.667,9.551-9.551,4.667,4.667-.667.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0,4l2.667,2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,4,0L59.516,27.5a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0-4Z" transform="translate(1 1.001)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>
            </svg>

      </div>
      <div class="legal-overlay">
        <!-- legal heading -->
        <h2>Legal Notices</h2>
        <!-- legal text -->
        <p> Published every Wednesday<br><i>Deadline every Friday at 3pm!</i></p>
      </div>
      <!-- legal button -->
      <button class="btn-legal">Learn More</button>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-4 featured-news-wrapper">
  <!-- subscribe link-->
  <a href="  ">
    <div class="featured--subscribe">

      <div class="subscribe-overlay-logo">

      </div>
      <div class="subscribe-overlay">
        <!-- subscribe text-->
        <p>Subscribe <br>And Never miss and issue</p>
        <!-- subscribe image -->
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/subscribe.png">
      </div>
      <!-- subscribe button -->
      <button class="btn-subscribe">Subscribe From $5</button>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Set `display:flex` on the body and `flex:1` on the wrappers you have `.col-4.featured-news-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Look into flexbox for various ways to align the elements you are referring to. It will make it super simple. Here is a basic example of the structure of the layout.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: teal;
}
.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: DarkOrchid;
}
.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.item__inner__photo {
  max-width: 120px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/uuhbg.clmqc/v/vspfiles/photos/00028861-2.jpg?v-cache=1522302835" alt="" class="item__inner__photo">
      <h3 class="item__inner__headline">
        This is a headline
      </h3>
      <p class="item__inner__content">Add some content here!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/uuhbg.clmqc/v/vspfiles/photos/00028861-2.jpg?v-cache=1522302835" alt="" class="item__inner__photo">
      <h3 class="item__inner__headline">
        This is a headline
      </h3>
      <p class="item__inner__content">Add some content here!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/uuhbg.clmqc/v/vspfiles/photos/00028861-2.jpg?v-cache=1522302835" alt="" class="item__inner__photo">
      <h3 class="item__inner__headline">
        This is a headline
      </h3>
      <p class="item__inner__content">Add some content here!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a `container` class and inside it you want a `row` and inside that you want to have the columns. i also added a `column` class to remove the default padding of `col-4` . (Take a look at the snippet in Full Page Mode)

```
.column {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

```css
/*Legal Notice Styling*/
.featured--legal--notices {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1a1a1a;
}

.featured--legal--notices .btn-legal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 89%;
  left: 28%;
  transform: translate(5%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #01ad54;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.legal-overlay-logo {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 43%;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 15rem;
}
.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay i {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .featured--legal--notices .bob-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 34%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--legal--notices .btn-listen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #01ad54;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56%;
    left: 32%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 35%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .featured--legal--notices .bob-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 34%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--legal--notices .btn-listen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #01ad54;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56%;
    left: 29%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/*END OF legal notice STYLING*/

/*Readers Styling*/
.featured--readers {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 118, 57) 0%, rgb(39, 173, 84) 100%);
}

.featured--readers .btn-readers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 89%;
  left: 28%;
  transform: translate(5%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.readers-overlay-logo {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 43%;
}

.featured--readers .readers-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 17rem;
}
.featured--readers .readers-overlay h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.featured--readers .readers-overlay p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--readers.readers-overlay i {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--readers.readers-overlay-white {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.featured--readers .readers-overlay-white p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .featured--readers .bob-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 34%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--readers .btn-readers {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .featured--readers .readers-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--readers .readers-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56%;
    left: 32%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--readers .readers-overlay-white {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 35%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--readers .readers-overlay-white p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .featured--readers .bob-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 34%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--readers .btn-readers {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .featured--readers .readers-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56%;
    left: 29%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--readers.readers-overlay-white p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/*END OF Readers STYLING*/

/*subscribe Styling*/
.featured--subscribe {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 118, 57) 0%, rgb(39, 173, 84) 100%);
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--subscribe .btn-subscribe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 89%;
  left: 20%;
  transform: translate(5%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.subscribe-overlay-logo {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 43%;
}

.featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 17rem;
}

.featured--subscribe .readers-subscribe p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--subscribe.subscribe-overlay i {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--subscribe.subscribe-overlay-white {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay-white p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .featured--subscribe .bob-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 34%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--subscribe .btn-subscribe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56%;
    left: 32%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay-white {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 35%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay-white p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .featured--subscribe .bob-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 34%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--subscribe .btn-subscribe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56%;
    left: 29%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .featured--subscribe.subscribe-overlay-white p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

.column {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- BootStrap 4 CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />


   
    <title> App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 column featured-news-wrapper">
          <a href=" ">
            <div class="featured--readers">
              <div class="readers-overlay-logo"></div>
              <div class="readers-overlay">
                <!-- svg beside main text -->
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="58.373"
                  height="63.352"
                  viewBox="0 0 58.373 63.352"
                >
                  <path
                    id="Path_1275"
                    data-name="Path 1275"
                    d="M34.794,67.261l.22-26.139a.173.173,0,0,0-.312-.1L26.813,51.883A8.568,8.568,0,0,1,13.291,41.36a8.57,8.57,0,0,1,6.589-15.82l11.983,5.469a.167.167,0,0,0,.224-.086.152.152,0,0,0-.027-.177L22.875,19.514A8.57,8.57,0,0,1,36.5,9.115a8.568,8.568,0,0,1,13.619,10.4L41.211,30.4a.175.175,0,0,0,.022.241.179.179,0,0,0,.176.027l12.637-5.066a8.57,8.57,0,0,1,5.839,16.114,8.567,8.567,0,0,1-14,9.874L39.119,41.285a.169.169,0,0,0-.237-.049.181.181,0,0,0-.081.146,40.994,40.994,0,0,0,3.65,16.554Zm6.346-9.5a42.025,42.025,0,0,1-3.46-16.372,1.3,1.3,0,0,1,2.377-.719L46.8,50.955a7.447,7.447,0,0,0,12.037-8.773,7.124,7.124,0,0,0-.988-1.1,7.447,7.447,0,1,0-3.408-14.419L41.821,31.717a1.3,1.3,0,0,1-1.481-2.023l8.89-10.876A7.444,7.444,0,1,0,37.255,9.974a7.271,7.271,0,0,0-.758,1.272,7.445,7.445,0,1,0-13.489,6.3,7.005,7.005,0,0,0,.751,1.266l9.17,11.22a1.289,1.289,0,0,1-1.534,1.99L19.434,26.575a7.445,7.445,0,1,0-5.506,13.834,7.219,7.219,0,0,0,1.421.407,7.445,7.445,0,0,0,9.53,11.44,7.1,7.1,0,0,0,1.041-1.051L33.792,40.36a1.295,1.295,0,0,1,2.34.768l-.188,22.967Z"
                    transform="translate(-7.591 -5.321)"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="#fff"
                    stroke-width="1"
                  />
                </svg>
                <!-- main text -->
                <h1>100,000</h1>
                <!-- sub text-->
                <p>Readers<br />with advertising</p>
              </div>
              <!-- text at the top -->
              <div class="readers-overlay-white">
                <p>Reach Over</p>
              </div>
              <!-- readers button -->
              <button class="btn-readers">Learn More</button>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 column featured-news-wrapper">
          <a href="">
            <div class="featured--legal--notices">
              <div class="legal-overlay-logo">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="62.576"
                  height="62.344"
                  viewBox="0 0 62.576 62.344"
                >
                  <path
                    id="gavel-solid"
                    d="M59.516,23.5l-2.667-2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0-4,0l-.667.667L38.847,8.162l.667-.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0-4L36.847.828a2.829,2.829,0,0,0-4,0L18.179,15.5a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0,4l2.667,2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,4,0l.667-.667,4.667,4.667-9.551,9.551-.667-.667a3.771,3.771,0,0,0-5.334,0L1.1,48.571a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,0,5.334l5.334,5.334a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,5.334,0L25.3,45.715a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,0-5.334l-.667-.667,9.551-9.551,4.667,4.667-.667.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0,4l2.667,2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,4,0L59.516,27.5a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0-4Z"
                    transform="translate(1 1.001)"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="#fff"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  />
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class="legal-overlay">
                <!-- legal heading -->
                <h2>Legal Notices</h2>
                <!-- legal text -->
                <p>
                  Published every Wednesday<br /><i
                    >Deadline every Friday at 3pm!</i
                  >
                </p>
              </div>
              <!-- legal button -->
              <button class="btn-legal">Learn More</button>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 column featured-news-wrapper">
          <!-- subscribe link-->
          <a href="  ">
            <div class="featured--subscribe">
              <div class="subscribe-overlay-logo"></div>
              <div class="subscribe-overlay">
                <!-- subscribe text-->
                <p>Subscribe <br />And Never miss and issue</p>
                <!-- subscribe image -->
                  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/subscribe.png">
              </div>
              <!-- subscribe button -->
              <button class="btn-subscribe">Subscribe From $5</button>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go and let me know if it's what you want. I've used Flexbox to align the elements next to each other as requested.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.featured-news-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Legal Notice Styling*/

.featured--legal--notices {
  background: #1A1A1A;
  height: 100%;
}

.featured--legal--notices .btn-legal {
  background-color: #01AD54;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.legal-overlay-logo svg {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay i {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--legal--notices .legal-overlay-white p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}


/*END OF legal notice STYLING*/


/*Readers Styling*/

.featured--readers {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 118, 57) 0%, rgb(39, 173, 84) 100%);
  height: 100%;
}

.featured--readers .btn-readers {
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.readers-overlay-logo svg {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.featured--readers .readers-overlay h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.featured--readers .readers-overlay p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--readers.readers-overlay i {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--readers.readers-overlay-white {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.featured--readers .readers-overlay-white p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}


/*END OF Readers STYLING*/


/*subscribe Styling*/

.featured--subscribe {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 118, 57) 0%, rgb(39, 173, 84) 100%);
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}

.featured--subscribe .btn-subscribe {
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.subscribe-overlay p {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.subscribe-overlay-logo svg {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.featured--subscribe .readers-subscribe p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--subscribe.subscribe-overlay i {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.featured--subscribe.subscribe-overlay-white {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.featured--subscribe .subscribe-overlay-white p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}


/*END OF Readers STYLING*/
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-4 featured-news-wrapper">
    <a href=" ">
      <div class="featured--readers">
        <div class="readers-overlay-logo">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="58.373" height="63.352" viewBox="0 0 58.373 63.352">
             <path id="Path_1275" data-name="Path 1275" d="M34.794,67.261l.22-26.139a.173.173,0,0,0-.312-.1L26.813,51.883A8.568,8.568,0,0,1,13.291,41.36a8.57,8.57,0,0,1,6.589-15.82l11.983,5.469a.167.167,0,0,0,.224-.086.152.152,0,0,0-.027-.177L22.875,19.514A8.57,8.57,0,0,1,36.5,9.115a8.568,8.568,0,0,1,13.619,10.4L41.211,30.4a.175.175,0,0,0,.022.241.179.179,0,0,0,.176.027l12.637-5.066a8.57,8.57,0,0,1,5.839,16.114,8.567,8.567,0,0,1-14,9.874L39.119,41.285a.169.169,0,0,0-.237-.049.181.181,0,0,0-.081.146,40.994,40.994,0,0,0,3.65,16.554Zm6.346-9.5a42.025,42.025,0,0,1-3.46-16.372,1.3,1.3,0,0,1,2.377-.719L46.8,50.955a7.447,7.447,0,0,0,12.037-8.773,7.124,7.124,0,0,0-.988-1.1,7.447,7.447,0,1,0-3.408-14.419L41.821,31.717a1.3,1.3,0,0,1-1.481-2.023l8.89-10.876A7.444,7.444,0,1,0,37.255,9.974a7.271,7.271,0,0,0-.758,1.272,7.445,7.445,0,1,0-13.489,6.3,7.005,7.005,0,0,0,.751,1.266l9.17,11.22a1.289,1.289,0,0,1-1.534,1.99L19.434,26.575a7.445,7.445,0,1,0-5.506,13.834,7.219,7.219,0,0,0,1.421.407,7.445,7.445,0,0,0,9.53,11.44,7.1,7.1,0,0,0,1.041-1.051L33.792,40.36a1.295,1.295,0,0,1,2.34.768l-.188,22.967Z" transform="translate(-7.591 -5.321)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" />
           </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="readers-overlay">
          <p>Reach Over</p>
          <h1>100,000 </h1>
          <p> Readers<br>with advertising </p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn-readers">Learn More</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 featured-news-wrapper">
    <a href="   ">
      <div class="featured--legal--notices">

        <div class="legal-overlay-logo">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="62.576" height="62.344" viewBox="0 0 62.576 62.344">
             <path id="gavel-solid" d="M59.516,23.5l-2.667-2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0-4,0l-.667.667L38.847,8.162l.667-.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0-4L36.847.828a2.829,2.829,0,0,0-4,0L18.179,15.5a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0,4l2.667,2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,4,0l.667-.667,4.667,4.667-9.551,9.551-.667-.667a3.771,3.771,0,0,0-5.334,0L1.1,48.571a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,0,5.334l5.334,5.334a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,5.334,0L25.3,45.715a3.771,3.771,0,0,0,0-5.334l-.667-.667,9.551-9.551,4.667,4.667-.667.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0,4l2.667,2.667a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,4,0L59.516,27.5a2.829,2.829,0,0,0,0-4Z" transform="translate(1 1.001)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" />
           </svg>

        </div>
        <div class="legal-overlay">

          <h2>Legal Notices</h2>
          <p> Published every Wednesday<br><i>Deadline every Friday at 3pm!</i></p>
        </div>

        <button class="btn-legal">Learn More</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 featured-news-wrapper">
    <a href="  ">
      <div class="featured--subscribe">

        <div class="subscribe-overlay-logo">
        </div>
        <div class="subscribe-overlay">
          <p>Subscribe <br>And Never miss and issue</p>
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/subscribe.png">
        </div>

        <button class="btn-subscribe">Subscribe From $5</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lasxr3kb/1/